# how to create javascript object dynamically inside a function

Tags: javascript

I want to create a javascript object dynamically each time when I call "dataObject" function, so I wanted to do something like that :

```
let dataObject = {};

function appendDiv() {
    e = this.event.target;

    //this id changes each time when the function is called
    var current_id = e.id;

    // here I had to initialized it because if I didn't, it would appear an error "TypeError: dataObject[(intermediate value)] is undefined"
    dataObject[`${current_id}`] = {};

    $('#creates').submit(function (event) {
        var i, j;

        for (i = 0; i < nbr_group.value; i++) {
            inputlist = [];

            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                formChild = document.querySelectorAll('.period-select')[j].value;
                inputlist[j] = formChild;
            }

            dataObject[`${current_id}`][`${i}`] = {
                firstvalue: inputlist[0], 
                secondvalue: inputlist[1], 
                thirdvalue: inputlist[2]    
            }
        }
    });    
}
```

so the problem is when the function is called for the first time the subobjects will be created successfully but the second call for the function will be create them empty, for example:

```
// the first call:
dataObject = {
    '1': {
         '1': { '1': 'some values' }, 
         '2': { '1': 'another value' }
    }
};

//the second call or third or... :
dataObject = {
    '1': {
        '1': { '1': 'some values' }, 
        '2': { '1': 'another value' }
    },
    '2': {}
};
```

Comment: Could you add your HTML? Without it it is unclear how this code works. When is `appendDiv()` called, and is it called multiple times? What does `this.event.target;` refer to? Which `input` fields are there?

Comment: actually this function is pretty long so I can say that this function is called by 20 of : "<span class="our_cell our_target" onclick="appendDiv(this);" id="1">the first cell</span>"  and the inputs will be created dynamically inside a form

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to copy an object, don't use `` dataObject[`${current_id}`][`${i}`] = {firstvalue: inputlist[0], secondvalue: inputlist[1], thirdvalue: inputlist[2]}; ``, use this:
`let objectCopy = Object.assign({}, dataObject);`
where `dataObject` is your object you would like to duplicate.